# Inline angularJs in html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to generate a html page that works offline without any access to a webserver (file opened with an url like file:///PathToMyFile.html). In this page I use some JS libraries and CSS I have inlined in header but for AngularJS it fails because there are some HTML codes inside AngularJS.js file.
How can i do that.
For information, I do the generation with the Twirl template engine (Scala).

Thanks

```
<head>
    <style>
        bootstrapCSSLib
    </style>

    <script>
        jqueryLib
        boostrapLib
        angularJSLib
    </script>
</head>
```

Edit : Real code truncated because too big:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<style>
    /*!
     * Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)
     * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.  BLABLABLA FULL BOOTSTRAP.CSS CONTENT
</style>

<script>

     /*! jQuery v2.1.4 BLA BLA BLA FULL JQUERY.JS CONTENT
     /*!
      * Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com) BLA BLA BLA FULL BOOTSTRAP.JS CONTENT
     /**
     * @license AngularJS v1.4.2
     * (c) 2010-2015 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
     * License: MIT  BLA BLA BLA FULL ANGULAR.JS CONTENT
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

Comment: Could you post the content of your angular file?

Comment: Use manual bootstrap of AngularJS app from JavaScript code.

Comment: If you don't have access to a webserver (even local server), you won't be able to load jquery ahah

Comment: @Slbteam08 Angular file is the AngularJS v1.4.2 file

Comment: The HTML file is open with a browser with url=file:///pathToMyFile.html

Comment: Should not have problems if including AngularJS core file. Could you post the content of the HTML above, not just pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include angular like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        inline angular script
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It works with this solution + using angular.min.js instead of angular.js (comments are breaking the syntax). Thank you Manos !

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJS site:

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greetMe = 'World';
      }]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Sure, this part of code is in <body> but it will work only if angularJS is correctly imported in <header>. It is not the case.